# Shortest Python 3 for sum of arithmetic progression

Tags: tips, python

**Input**: from STDIN number of vertices in Graph \$2 \leq N \leq 100\$.

**Rules**: [Code size] = max ([code length without spaces, tabs and newlines], [total code length divided by 4])

**Math formulation**: In the graph of N vertices, between each pair of vertices can be 3 road states:

- there is no road
- there is a road from A to B
- there is a road from B to A

**Find the number of different graphs on given vertices.**

We can apply next formula (number of different road states in pow of pairs number): $$\huge3 ^ {\frac{n(n - 1)}{2}}$$.

## My [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) 37 bytes solution here:

```
n = int(input())
print(3 ** ((n ** 2 - n) // 2))
```

I know that exists **34 bytes** solution. Then I started to think about 1 liner, and find next formula for sum of arithmetic progression, which use N only once:
$$\frac{(2n - 1) ^ 2}{8} - \frac18$$

Unfortunately the code only increased:

```
x = 2 * int(input()) - 1
print(3 ** ((x ** 2 - 1) // 8))
```

Comment: This is not enough, but `n**2` = `n*n`.

Comment: If someone knows how to make inline latex formula, pls edit my question. I don't know why it's not working here.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I looked at this formula for 3 hours and did not see an elephant, thank you.

Comment: Does the title really match the challenge text?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure, but it's the main part of this code which you can make shorter.

Comment: Note that your 2nd formula can be turned into a [38-byte one-liner](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1hLS0PDSAvEzMwrKC3R0NTUNdTU0jLSNbSzM9bU/P/fFAA). But of course, that's still too long.

Comment: @Arnauld I think you can remove the `-1` too, but 36 bytes is still too long.

Comment: Can the output be produced as a whole-number float like `27.0`?

Comment: @xnor No, only int allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes (not counting the newline)

Uses the conventional formula for the sum of the arithmetic progression (\$\frac{n(n-1)}2\$) and the trick that `n-1` = `~-n` (but with higher operator precedence). This way, one pair of parentheses can be omitted.

```python
n=int(input())
print(3**(n*~-n//2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIxDXW0tLI06rTzdPXN9LU/P/fFAA)

Comment: Is it possible to get real binary representation of -n? How many bits it use? Because for n = -6, bin(n) give me '-0b110'. I'm trying to understand how is it working.

Comment: @Evgeny You may want to read the Wikipedia article on [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Flipping all bits of `n` simply results in `-n-1`. (of course, that's what flipping all bits does in languages with machine-word-sized integers, but in many other languages `~` has the same behaviour)

Comment: Tank you. It's impossible to solve the problem without this sacred knowledge.

Comment: @Evgeny Is Python 3 mandatory? Based on your question title I assume it is, but if not, this could be [2 bytes shorter in Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIyFUw1tLSyNOq083TN9L8/98UAA) (`print a` instead of `print(a)` and `/` instead of `//` which uses integer division implicitly on integers).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `int(...)` is also not necessary. (if this is a problem from acmp.ru, like OP's previous question, then Python 3 seems to be mandatory)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, only Python3 allowed.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
print(3**sum(range(int(input()))))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1hLq7g0V6MoMS89VQMkkJlXUFqioQkC//8bGgAA)**

In Python 2 this is just `print 3**sum(range(input()))` for 28.

Comment: Why does this answer have five times as many upvotes as mine? (I think they're mostly the same) Am I doing something wrong? (note: the question I am trying to ask is not "where are my upvotes" but "what am I doing wrong or what can I do better")

Comment: I posted this because it was a one-liner, which OP said they started thinking about. I'm not sure why it has so many more upvotes as I would not class this as a "better" code-golf solution (given the altered scoring mechanism), just an alternative one. You've certainly done nothing wrong.